# Does a user-defined drop for a struct also drop its fields implicitly in Rust?

Tags: rust, raii

Let's say I have a struct

```rust
struct Foo {
    a: Box<usize>,
    b: Box<usize>,
}
```

And I'd like to do something with a and b when dropping a Foo instance like this

```rust
impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("{}", self.a + self.b);
    }
}
```

Will Box a and b get dropped after this `drop`?
Does my drop implementation overwrites the default impl for drop? Like what's the actual workflow here?

Moreover, if I manually call something like `foo.drop()`, this only does what I implemented but not actually dropping two boxes. How do I make sure they are dropped?

Comment: You cannot call `drop()` explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will Box a and b get dropped after this `drop`? Does my drop implementation overwrites the default impl for drop?

Rust's drop glue will ensure that the fields of `Foo` are dropped in the order they are declared, *after* your custom drop implementation.  So, in this case, when a `Foo` gets dropped:

- `<Foo as Drop>::drop()` is invoked on the `Foo`.
- The `Foo`'s `a` is dropped.
- The `Foo`'s `b` is dropped.

We can prove this to ourselves with the following program:

```
#![allow(unused)]

struct Foo {
    a: Bar,
    b: Bar,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            a: Bar("a"),
            b: Bar("b"),
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Foo dropped");
    }
}

struct Bar(&'static str);

impl Drop for Bar {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Bar named \"{}\" dropped", self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    Foo::new();
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
Foo dropped
Bar named "a" dropped
Bar named "b" dropped
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=74e1436bd8059d9fdf4fd2a7510724c3))

> Moreover, if I manually call something like `foo.drop()`, this only does what I implemented but not actually dropping two boxes.

You *can't* manually call `Drop::drop()`.  This is a special case in the Rust language.  If you attempt to call `foo.drop()` the compiler will reject your program:

```
error[E0040]: explicit use of destructor method
```

Comment: By the way, this is literally the first thing mentioned in the documentation of the `Drop` trait: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html

Comment: @cadolphs Yep. I was looking for a reference in the Rust book, but I couldn't find one. I didn't think to look at the API documentation.

Comment: Drop is Rust builtin so doc to find drop mechanic in rust is the trait drop. that what I like in like, trait define language mechanic. like Add, Copy etc...